# Matplotlib is processing but could not download using pip

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
C:\Users\Sheetal1.Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib

  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/56/569c83515c10146fd0a
a09e086816b12e301d0811048e3354a6e9b77ba9a/matplotlib-3.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.
whl

C:\Users\Sheetal1.Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib

Collecting matplotlib

  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/56/569c83515c10146fd0aa
09e086816b12e301d0811048e3354a6e9b77ba9a/matplotlib-3.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.w
hl (8.9MB)

    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.9MB 12.8MB/s

C:\Users\Sheetal1.Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip install matplotlib==1.5.1

Collecting matplotlib==1.5.1

  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/f4/c0c7e81f64d5f4d36e52
e393af687f28882c53dcd924419d684dc9859f40/matplotlib-1.5.1.tar.gz (54.0MB)

    100% |████████████████████████████████| 54.0MB 18kB/s
```

I have tried the above 3 versions to install matplotlib package in python 3.6 but after complete processing, the exe file is not seen in the folder. It does not display any error so I cannot understand where the problem lies.

```
import matplotlib
```

raises error

> Module Not Found Error

Comment: `pip` doesn't install any exe files, it installs Python modules. If running `import matplotlib` in Python doesn't raise any exceptions after installation, everything has been installed successfully

Comment: But "import matplotlib" raises error as "Module Not Found Error"

Answer (score 0):

> Open cmd as administrator and type : pip3 install matplotlib

Comment: Even pip 3 did not work for me... As mentioned above with the error, it does not give "Successfully installed matplotlib" message at the end of installation and that is where I am getting "Module not found error" while importing matplotlib...This case goes only for matplotlib package as other packages are downloaded successfully. The same package is downloaded successfully in Python 2 version.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I would say you're not installing to the correct library that is being used by the `python` interpreter.

Do you have [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) installed?

If so you will need to install packages using `conda install` to install packages.